# Lightweight, minimalistic, viable CMS to learn Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system

What CMS would you suggest to learn Ruby On Rails?

Some criteria:

1. It's minimalistic, lightweight but viable
2. Great software design
3. Good documentation
4. Active community
5. Internationalization

Thanks, 
Alpha Sisyphus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd head to http://refinerycms.com/

This one is great too: http://www.locomotivecms.com/